# Apply visual styling to echo commands used in npm scripts via package.json

Tags: npm, echo, package.json, build-tools, npm-scripts

Have recently put together a build tool with `npm` and `package.json` scripts, and I have a few `echo` commands to state which parts of the pipeline are currently running.

For example (from my `package.json`):

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf a-directory/",
        "preclean": "echo \"\n[ Cleaning build directories ]\n\""
    }
}
```

When I Bash: `npm run clean` it prints my `echo` message, and then cleans the appropriate directory.

I'd like to change colour, font weight, background text colour to make these `echo` statements stand out and be more informative at a glance, but I've struggled even finding a starting point that can set me off being able to do this.

There's lots of info about doing this in regular CLI/Bash scripts, via `grunt` and `gulp`, or via JS scripts, but nothing I've found is attempting it from the scripts section of `package.json`.

What am I missing? All help appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Consoles/terminals typically provide support for [ANSI/VT100 Control sequences](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting), so it's possible to use these codes to control font colour, font weight, background colour, etc.

- For a Bash only solution refer to the *Bash (MacOS/Linux/ etc..)* section below.
- However, if cross platform support is required then follow the solution described in the *Cross Platform* section below.

---

### Bash (MacOS/Linux/ etc..)

**Important Note:** The following will not work successfully on non-bash consoles, such as *Windows Command Prompt* (i.e. cmd.exe) or *PowerShell*.

This example npm-script below:

```json
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rimraf a-directory/",
  "preclean": "echo \"\\x1b[104m\\x1b[97m\n[ Cleaning build directories ]\n\\x1b[0m\""
}
```

...will log the something like the following in your console when running `npm run clean`(i.e. white text with a blue colored background):

[image]

#### Breakdown of the necessary syntax/codes:

```
            <Esc> characters
   ┌─────────┬────┴─────────┐
   │         │              │
 ┌─┴─┐     ┌─┴─┐          ┌─┴─┐
 \\x1b[104m\\x1b[97m Mssg \\x1b[0m
      └─┬─┘     └─┬┘└─┬─┘      └┬┘
        │         │   │         │
        │         │   │         │
        │         │   │         │
        │         │   │  Reset all attributes
        │         │   │
        │         │  Your Message
        │         │
        │       White Text
        │       
 Light blue background
```

#### Further examples:

The following example npm-scripts provide further examples:

```json
"scripts": {
  "a": "echo \"\\x1b[1m\\x1b[39mBold Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "b": "echo \"\\x1b[91mLight Red Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "c": "echo \"\\x1b[94mLight Blue Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "d": "echo \"\\x1b[92mLight Green Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "e": "echo \"\\x1b[4m\\x1b[91mLight Red Underlined Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "f": "echo \"\\x1b[101m\\x1b[97mLight Red Background and White Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "g": "echo \"\\x1b[104m\\x1b[97mLight Blue Background and White Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "h": "echo \"\\x1b[30m\\x1b[103mLight Yellow Background and Black Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "i": "echo \"\\x1b[97m\\x1b[100mDark Gray Background and White Text\\x1b[0m\"",
  "bash-echo-all": "npm run a -s && npm run b -s && npm run c -s && npm run d -s && npm run e -s && npm run f -s && npm run g -s && npm run h -s && npm run i -s"
},
```

Running `npm run bash-echo-all -s` using the scripts above will output the following to your console (the `-s` option just makes npm log a bit less):

[image]

A more comprehensive list of codes can be found at the link provided at the top of this post, (or see codes listed in *Cross Platform* section below), but remember not all ANSI/VT100 Control sequences are supported.

---

### Cross Platform

For a cross-platform solution, (one which works successfully with *Bash*, *Windows Command Prompt / cmd.exe*, and *PowerShell* etc..), you'll need to create a nodejs utility script to handle the logging. This nodejs script can then be invoked via your `npm-scripts`.

The following steps describe how this can be achieved:

1. Create a nodejs utility script as follows:

   **echo.js**

   ```js
   const args = process.argv;    
   const mssg = args[2];

   const opts = [
     '-s', '--set',
     '-b', '--bg-color',
     '-f', '--font-color'];

   function excapeAnsiCode(code) {
     return '\x1b[' + code + 'm';
   }

   const ansiStyles = opts.map(function (opt) {
     return args.indexOf(opt) > -1
         ? excapeAnsiCode(args[args.indexOf(opt) +1])
         : '';
   });

   console.log('%s%s%s', ansiStyles.join(''), mssg, '\x1b[0m');
   ```

   Let's name the file `echo.js` and save it in the root of your project directory, i.e. in the same folder where `package.json` is stored.
2. Then, given your example, let's add a `npm-script` to `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "rimraf a-directory/",
     "preclean": "node echo \"[ Cleaning build directories ]\" --bg-color 104 --font-color 97"
   }
   ```

   When running `npm run clean` you'll see the same message logged to your console as before when using the *bash* only solution, i.e. white text with a blue colored background.

   [image]

#### Overview of usage syntax for invoking `echo.js` via `npm-scripts`

```
node echo \"message\" [[-s|--set] number] [[-b|--bg-color] number] [[-f|--font-color] number]
```

1. **`node echo \"message\"`**

   The `node echo \"message\"` part is mandatory. The `message` is where you enter your message to be logged and it *must* be wrapped in escaped double quotes `\"...\"` to prevent splitting.

   The remaining parts, which are for the purpose of formatting/styling, are all optional and can be defined in any order. However, when used, they must proceed after the initial `node echo \"message\"` part, and be separated by a single space.
2. **[`--set|-s`]**

   The `--set` option, or it's shorthand equivalent  `-s`, followed by a single space, and one of the following ANSI codes can be used to specify general formatting:

   ```
   ┌─────────────────────────┐
   │ Code  Description       │
   ├─────────────────────────┤
   │  1    Bold/Bright       │
   │  2    Dim               │
   │  4    Underlined        │
   │  5    Blink             │
   │  7    Reverse/invert    │
   │  8    Hidden            │
   └─────────────────────────┘
   ```

   **Note**: Codes `1` and `4` worked successfully with *Bash*, however they were not supported by *Windows Command Prompt* and *Powershell*. So if repeatability is important across platforms I recommend avoiding use of the `--set`|`-s` option entirely.
3. **[`--bg-color|-b`]**

   The `--bg-color` option, or it's shorthand equivalent `-b`, followed by a single space, and one of the following ANSI codes can be used to specify the background color:

   ```
   ┌─────────────────────────┐
   │ Code  Background Color  │
   ├─────────────────────────┤
   │  49   Default           │
   │  40   Black             │
   │  41   Red               │
   │  42   Green             │
   │  43   Yellow            │
   │  44   Blue              │
   │  45   Magenta           │
   │  46   Cyan              │
   │  47   Light Gray        │
   │  100  Dark Gray         │
   │  101  Light Red         │
   │  102  Light Green       │
   │  103  Light Yellow      │
   │  104  Light Blue        │
   │  105  Light Magenta     │
   │  106  Light Cyan        │
   │  107  White Cyan        │
   └─────────────────────────┘
   ```
4. **[`--font-color|-f`]**

   The `--font-color` option, or it's shorthand equivalent  `-f`, followed by a single space, and one of the following ANSI codes can be used to specify the font color:

   ```
   ┌─────────────────────────┐
   │ Code  Font Color        │
   ├─────────────────────────┤
   │  39   Default           │
   │  30   Black             │
   │  31   Red               │
   │  32   Green             │
   │  33   Yellow            │
   │  34   Blue              │
   │  35   Magenta           │
   │  36   Cyan              │
   │  37   Light Gray        │
   │  90   Dark Gray         │
   │  91   Light Red         │
   │  92   Light Green       │
   │  93   Light Yellow      │
   │  94   Light Blue        │
   │  95   Light Magenta     │
   │  96   Light Cyan        │
   │  97   White Cyan        │
   └─────────────────────────┘
   ```

#### Further examples:

The following example scripts provide further examples:

```json
"scripts": {
  "r": "node echo \"Bold Text\" -s 1",
  "s": "node echo \"Light Red Text\" -f 91",
  "t": "node echo \"Light Blue Text\" -f 94",
  "u": "node echo \"Light Green Text\" -f 92",
  "v": "node echo \"Light Red Underlined Text\" -s 4 -f 91",
  "w": "node echo \"Light Red Background and White Text\" -b 101 -f 97",
  "x": "node echo \"Light Blue Background and White Text\" -b 104 -f 97",
  "y": "node echo \"Light Yellow Background and Black Text\" -f 30 -b 103",
  "z": "node echo \"Dark Gray Background and White Text\" -b 100 -f 97",
  "node-echo-all": "npm run r -s && npm run s -s && npm run t -s && npm run u -s && npm run v -s && npm run w -s && npm run x -s && npm run y -s && npm run z -s"
},
```

Running `npm run node-echo-all -s` using the scripts above will output the the same results as shown in the *Bash (MacOS/Linux/ etc..)* section above.

For brevity these scripts (above) utilize the shorthand `-s`, `-b`, and `-f` options. However they can be substituted with their longhand equivalents `--set`, `--bg-color`, and `--font-color` respectively if necessary to make your code more human readable.