# Output to command line within npm scripts?

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a script in my package.json with the following code:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css",
    "watch": "postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css --watch"
}
```

It works fine. but how do I get it to output text to the command line, something like

```
script ran at {{ date(now) }}
```

In other words, I want to see a notification when a script has run.

Comment: Thanks @RobC. This is what I had in mind. For the --watch part of the script, is there a way to get output to the command line when the script runs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Cross Platform (Windows/Linux/macOS...)

You can do the following to log the date/time when the script begins its task:

```json
"build": "node -e \"console.log('script started at: %s', Date())\" && postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css"
```

#### Explanation:

1. The part on the left side of the `&&` operator that reads;

   ```
   node -e \"console.log('script started at: %s', Date())\"
   ```

   - utilizes Node.js command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) to evaluate the inline JavaScript.
   - The inline script utilizes JavaScript's `console.log(...)` and [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
2. The commands on the right side of the `&&` operator are whatever command(s) you want to run, in your scenario it's the `postcss` command.

#### Variations:

- To color the log you could add some [ANSI/VT100 Control sequences](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting). For instance:

  ```json
  "build": "node -e \"console.log('%sscript started at: %s%s', '\\x1b[42;30m', Date(), '\\x1b[0m' )\" && postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css"
  ```
- To log when the npm script completed instead of started you can switch the order of the commands. For example:

  ```json
  "build": "postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css && node -e \"console.log('script completed at: %s', Date())\""
  ```

---

### Nix platforms only (Linux/MacOS...)

If you only want a solution that runs on **nix* platforms, then you can do the following instead:

```json
"build": "echo \"script started at: $(date)\" && postcss tailwind/tailwind.css -o css/cenic.tailwind.css"
```

#### Explanation:

1. The part on the left side of the `&&` operator that reads:

   ```
   echo \"script started at: $(date)\"
   ```

   - utilizes the shells [`echo`](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) command to print the message to the command line.
   - [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), i.e. the `$(...)` part, is utilized to obtain the output from the shells [`date`](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html) command.
2. The commands on the right side of the `&&` operator are whatever command(s) you want to run, in your scenario it's the `postcss` command.

If you want to apply visual styling to the `echo` command please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226385/apply-visual-styling-to-echo-commands-used-in-npm-scripts-via-package-json/50275198#50275198)