# How to get colors on the command line in npm nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Sometimes we need to show different command lines out of different colors.
Here is a solution which I found, which can helpful for other developers too.

Comment: ... and if you want different colors for messages generated via npm scripts - refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226385/apply-visual-styling-to-echo-commands-used-in-npm-scripts-via-package-json/50275198#50275198).

Answer (score 0):

First, install it to the directory you'd like to work in.

```
npm install colors
```

Now open up a little test script for yourself, and try something like this:

```
const colors = require('colors');

const string1 = 'This string is red.'.red;
const string2 = 'This string is blue.'.blue;

console.log(string1);
console.log(stringThree);
```

Answer (score 0):

npm chalk is another popular library

```
const chalk = require('chalk');

console.log(chalk.green('Hello world!'));
```

All you have to do is `npm install chalk` and you are all set.
[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) is the  link for more information.